# Forms with Min Characters Requirement

Tags: javascript, forms

I have the following Validate form that request that a person completes all the relevant blocks on the form. I am trying to have one Block have a min number of characters for that specific block only. Below is my current code

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var a=document.forms["lbs_trace"]["lbs_reason"].value;
var b=document.forms["lbs_trace"]["lbs_for"].value;
var c=document.forms["lbs_trace"]["lbs_type"].value;
var x=document.forms["lbs_trace"]["lbs_case"].value;
var y=document.forms["lbs_trace"]["lbs_terms"].value;
var count = 0;
    if (!(a==null|| a==""))
    {
        count++;
    }
    if (!(b==null|| b==""))
    {
        count++;
    }
    if (!(c==null|| c==""))
    {
        count++;
    }
  if (!(x==null || x==""))
  { 
    count++;
  }
  if (!(y==null || y==""))
  { 
     count++;
  }
  if(count < 5){
    alert("Please assure that the following has been completed, CASE TYPE, REQUESTED BY, DESCRIPTION, CASE NUMBER and TERMS AND CONDITIONS ARE TICKED");
    return false;     
  }



}
</script>
```

In ***VAR A*** I want a min of 30 Characters to be entered before continuing to process the form

Comment: Validation in Javascript not PHP?

Comment: @user1 One doesn't prevent the other ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a javascript tag, this isn't php.  Here's how to validate length:

```
if (!(a==null || a.length < 30))
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, I do apologize the page is in PHP the code is in Java Think my wording was poor.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a code like this:

```
var lbs_reason = document.forms["lbs_trace"]["lbs_reason"].value;
var lbs_for = document.forms["lbs_trace"]["lbs_for"].value;

if(lbs_reason == null || lbs_reason.length < 30 || lbs_for == null || lbs_for == "")
{
    // form not valid
}
```

You must do the same validations server-side, in PHP. Because Javascript may not be executed on the client and it's easy to craft HTTP requests.